how to show a context menu in a textView added by “windowManager.addView(view, params)”
I want to show a floating window using the windowManager.addView(view, params) API. However, after selecting text in the floating window, the text is highlighted, but the context menu doesn't appear. While I intend to build my own context menu, I can't even get the system context menu to show up.
Interestingly, using the same layout in another activity with setContentView(view), the text can be selected, and the system context menu shows up as expected.
